# How to add a new row into csv file which in inside sharepoint site using logic app?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I have `csv file inside sharepoint site`

I have `HTTP which will call API and gives input into array format`

I tried using `Sharepoint connector and updated file` but not able to add new data into file.

I have `converted csv to xsl doing save as` and used `excel connector` but not  `not found file`

How to add new data into existing csv file.?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need a third party connector for Flow or to to use an Azure function with Flow. If you use an Azure Function you can get a copy of the file, append the line then upload it.

Answer (score 1):

I think , you can have the excel in One Drive use that content as Table to make it as an array.. this will solve both your problem of updating and listing it as an array or list

[Sample List rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVfpx.png)